# PHP session array and input validation

Tags: php, arrays, forms, session

Currently I am sending error messages and storing the value of my input fields in sessions.

**Form example**

```
<label class="errormsg"><?php echo $_SESSION['msgProductPrice']; unset($_SESSION['msgProductPrice']); ?></label>

<input type="text" name="product_price" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['val_ProductPrice']; unset($_SESSION['val_ProductPrice']); ?>" />
```

**PHP**

```
$Price = $_POST['product_price'];
$errorcount = 0;

if(empty($Price) === true){
    $PriceErrormsg = "empty";
    $errorcount++;
}

if($errorcount === 0) {
   // success
} else {
   $_SESSION['val_ProductPrice'] = $Price;
   $_SESSION['msgProductPrice'] = $PriceErrormsg;
}
```

This works perfectly with one of a kind input field. If I try with multiple input fields with the same name, it doesn't work.

**Form example**

```
<label class="errormsg"><?php echo $_SESSION['msgProductAmount']; unset($_SESSION['msgProductAmount']); ?></label>
<input type="text" name="product_amount[]" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['val_ProductAmount']; unset($_SESSION['val_ProductAmount']); ?>" />

<label class="errormsg"><?php echo $_SESSION['msgProductAmount']; unset($_SESSION['msgProductAmount']); ?></label>
<input type="text" name="product_amount[]" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['val_ProductAmount']; unset($_SESSION['val_ProductAmount']); ?>" />
```

This is where I'm unsure on how to validate all the input fields, how to keep the value in each input field when you hit submit and how to send an errormsg about each field?

**PHP**

```
$Amount= $_POST['product_amount'];
$errorcount = 0;

if(empty($Amount) === true){
    $AmountErrormsg = "empty";
    $errorcount++;
}

if($errorcount === 0) {
   // success
} else {
   $_SESSION['val_ProductAmount'] = $Amount;
   $_SESSION['msgProductAmount'] = $AmountErrormsg;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem, multiple product amounts are being submitted, and you want to validate each one individually and display the error message next to the appropriate textbox?

Because you are receiving an array of values, you need to create a corresponding array of error messages.

It's a while since I've done any PHP, so this might not be 100% correct, but I think you need something along these lines...

```
$AmountErrorMessage = Array();
foreach ($Amount as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($value)) {
        $AmountErrorMessage[$key] = 'empty';
    }
}

if ($AmountErrorMessage->count() > 0) {
    // success
} else {
    $_SESSION['val_ProductAmount'] = $Amount;
    $_SESSION['msgProductAmount'] = $AmountErrorMessage;
}
```

You would then also need to iterate through the array in order to generate the HTML for your form, creating a label and input box for each value submitted.

Comment: Now it shows an error message but it just says array, same with the value in my input fields. [Imgur](http://imgur.com/AY0ZRw8) @UberDoodles

Comment: When you echo the error message, you need to echo a specific item from the array. E.g. "echo $_SESSION['msgProductAmount'][0];"

Comment: THANKS! Now the messages work :D

How would I make this work with the value? tried to do the same, but it doesn't work?

`<input type="text" name="product_amount[]" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['val_ProductAmount'][0]; unset($_SESSION['val_ProductAmount'][0]); ?>">

$ValueProductAmount = Array();
$AmountErrorMessage = Array();
    foreach ($Amount as $key => $value) {
    if(empty($value) {
        $AmountErrorMessage[$key] = 'empty';
        $ValueProductAmount[$value];
    }
}
`
@UberDoodles

Comment: Shouldn't "$ValueProductAmount[$value];" be "$ValueProductAmount[$key] = $value;"? Also I think that statement  should be outside the if(empty($value)) block, because you want to retain the value even if it is not invalid.

Comment: oh yeah. It needed to be = to something.. not sure what I was thinking with just this `$ValueProductAmount[$value];`. Thank you so much for the help! @UberDoodles

Answer (score 0):

This code help you to do it as per your wish..

```
<?php
    session_start();
    ?>    
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>    
        <style>
        .errormsg{
         color:red; 
        }
        </style>  
        </head>
        <body>    
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['product_amount']))
        {
          $errorcount = 0;
          for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['product_amount']);$i++){
            $Amount[$i] = $_POST['product_amount'][$i];  

            if(empty($Amount[$i]) === true){
                $_SESSION['msgProductAmount'][$i] = "empty";
                $errorcount++;
            }
            else
              $_SESSION['val_ProductAmount'][$i] = $Amount[$i];
          }
          if($errorcount === 0) {
             unset($_SESSION['msgProductAmount']); 
             echo "success";
          } 
        }
        ?>
        <form action="" method="POST">
        <?php
        $cnt = 10;
        for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++){
        ?>
        <input type="text" name="product_amount[<?=$i?>]" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['val_ProductAmount'][$i]) ? $_SESSION['val_ProductAmount'][$i] : '';?>" />
        <label class="errormsg"><?php echo $res = isset($_SESSION['msgProductAmount'][$i]) ? $_SESSION['msgProductAmount'][$i] : '' ; ?></label>
        <br/>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
        <?php
        unset($_SESSION['msgProductAmount'],$_SESSION['val_ProductAmount']);
        ?>
```